# How to symbolize "if any one of items in this list equals (value)" in notation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, I have a list of items{x,y,z}. I want to symbolize the statement 'if ***anyone of these items in my list {x,y,z} equals "Carrot" '***. I'm no math student - just trying to write some documentation for a process.

{x,y,z} == "Carrot" ... ?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to say is simply $``Carrot``\in\{x,y,z\}$ which literally reads as "the string "Carrot" is an element of the set $\{x,y,z\}$

Answer (score 1):

You want $\in$:
$$\text{carrot}\in \{x,y,z\}$$

The TeX and MathJax code for$\in$ is `\in`.

If you can't get $\in$, Greek letter epsilon ($\epsilon$) is an acceptable substitute.